# Visual Studio 2013 Test Explorer doesn't seem to work

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently using the professional version. There seems to be 2 windows, the Test Explorer and the Unit Test Session. I can run a test or all tests from my code (cs file) and see them in the Unit Test Session window. When I try to run via the Test menu item OR within the Test Explorer window, nothing happens and no tests get run. Am I missing something here? Is this a edition issue?

Comment: Are you using MS Test or a third party testing framework?

Comment: @NinjaCoding you need to install the nunit adapter to start seeing the nunit tests in the Test Explorer. The adapter is available online and you can get it quickly via the Tools->Extension, just search and install.

Comment: As Allen said you probably be missing the adapter. Just to rule out any other issues you can try the same with mstest. You can download the test adapter here http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ab922d0-21c0-4f06-ab5f-4ecd1fe7175d

Comment: Thank you. That was it!!. If you want to reply instead of commenting, I'll mark you as correct.

Answer (score 9):

Just ran into the same problem.

Install the `nunit adapter` for `Test Explorer`

(search for "nunit adapter" in NuGet and it will be the first hit).

After installing the addons, press `Run all` in test explorer again and voila: all nunit tests are discovered.

Comment: +1 This must be a typical trap .. thanks :) I expected that it would be able to run nunit tests out of the box.  But when I asserted that expectation it failed.

Comment: I've just spent few hours trying to fix this too. Turns out I had adapter installed as VS extension (.vsix downloaded from the webpage), this is the WRONG version, what you need is the actual nuget package version, just like in @bas answer. Only then it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this might not be your case but in my case I had a "test support classes" project with a  test base class amongst some other structures, and one of my test projects referencing this had another version of Moq installed.

So `Update-Package Moq` for all projects resolved my issue.